# Is there a way to update to Windows 10 1809 LTSC from earlier Windows 10 LTSB version remotely?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

Our customers have:

- over 200 Windows machines with Windows 10 Enterprise 2015 LTSB/1507/10240
- over 800 Windows machines with Windows 10 Enterprise 2016 LTSB/1607/14393

We have our UWP based POS app running on them, however - the app shared a big part of it's code-base with our other apps - Windows Services, Xamarin, ASP.NET Core Apps and other, from which all can use .NET Standard 2.0, but due to our UWP POS app on above mentioned windows versions, the shared code base needs to be in .NET Standard 1.4.

That begins to be a bigger and bigger issue with the ongoing development and more and more customers.

What is the easiest and safest way to update those machines to Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC 2019/1809/17763?

Is there any chance to do it remotely? (We have remote access to those machines via TeamViewer)

Comment: Is PowerShell an option?

Comment: But how exactly an option?

Comment: Not sure, just seems like PowerShell might be able to do it. I know you can update entire networks from it, so with PS yes you could it remotely and very easily. That said, I don't know what cmdlets you'd want to use, you'd have to look into that further